# Error [3504] Non-Aggregate Values with sum sub-select

Tags: sql, teradata

I've been working with Teradata pulling some information from a database. I'm familiar with the error I'm encountering where the group by isn't including one of my 'select' variables.

However, I went back and checked and should've gotten all my counts right. **I believe it has something to do with my last few sum functions**, since they are referencing another 'table' that I've created. Possibly needs to be casted as an int or something?

The reason why I can't query off the main table is that my main table, when I've tried to do the same thing, runs about 4.3M rows deep.

```
select  
isitable.PA_ID
,isitable.A_NM
,isitable.ISI_IND
,isitable.CAMP_ID
,sum(isitable.rewardAmount) as Reward_Amount
,sum(isitable.WP) as WP
,isitable.TM
,isitable.RM
,isitable.LOB
,isitable.Region
,isitable.OM_ID
,isitable.OM_NM
,isitable.BM_ID
,isitable.BM_NM
,isitable.State
,extract(month from isitable.QI_DATE) as QI_Month
,extract(year from isitable.QI_DATE) as QI_Year
,sum(isitable.ISI_Q) as ISI_Q
,sum(isitable.ISI_I) as ISI_I
,sum(isitable.Q) as Q
,sum(isitable.I) as I

from    
        (
SELECT  
        dim.GUID
        ,dim2.PA_ID
        ,dim2.A_NM
        ,ISI.CAMP_ID
        ,isi.rewardAmount
        ,
case    when fact.I = 1 then  fact.QPA 
else    0 
end as WP
        ,dim2.TM
        ,dim2.RM
        ,dim.LOB
        ,dim2.Region
        ,dim2.OM_ID
        ,dim2.OM_NM
        ,dim2.BM_ID
        ,dim2.BM_NM
        ,dim2.State
        ,fact.Q
        ,fact.I
        ,fact.D
        ,fact.QI_Date
        ,
case    when  dim.GUID = ISI.GUID  then 'Y' 
else    'N' 
end as ISI_Ind
        ,
case    when isi_ind = 'Y' then sum(fact.q_cnt) 
else    0 
end as ISI_Q
        ,
case    when isi_ind = 'Y' then sum(fact.i_cnt) 
else    0 
end as ISI_I
        ,
case    when isi_ind = 'N' then sum(fact.q_cnt) 
else    0 
end as Q
        ,
case    when isi_ind = 'N' then sum(fact.i_cnt) 
else    0 
end as I



        FROM facttable AS fact

                JOIN dimtable AS dim

                        ON fact.App_ID = dim.App_ID

                JOIN dimtable1 AS dim1

                        ON fact.Dist_D = dim1.Dist_ID

                JOIN dimtable2 AS dim2

                        ON dim1.A_ID = dim2.A_ID

                LEFT JOIN isitable as isi

                        ON dim.GUID = ISI.GUID

                left join isiusertable as isiuser

                    on isi.userid =  isiuser.userid


        where  QI_Date >= '2017-01-01'


        Group by 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18) as isitable

where   isitable.Camp_ID is null
    or isitable.Camp_ID in ('324', '325', '326', '327', '320', '323',
        '317', '319', '318', '313', '315', '316', '314', '301', '302',
        '298', '300', '299', '295', '297', '294', '296', '292', '293',
        '290', '287', '289', '288', '276', '277', '273', '274', '272',
        '269', '266', '263', '260', '258','244', '241','237', '236',
        '61')

group   by 1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17

order   by 1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
```

Apologies for any connection errors, had to censor out table names and joins as best as I could.

Comment: You probably need to add more columns to the inner GROUP BY.  Or you might need to move the CASE into the SUM like this: `sum(case    when isi_ind = 'Y' then fact.q_cnt
else    0 
end)` 
else    0 
end as ISI_Q

Comment: If I'm counting correctly, you have 20 non-aggregate columns in your inner select, you need to group by all of them.  And I think @dnoeth is correct as well, move the case inside the sum.

Comment: I found another case when outside of the sub-select that might've been causing the issue as well. Fixed that and adjusted the case whens and seems to be running now.

Thanks!